# Svg draw connection line between two rectangles

Tags: javascript, svg, connection, rectangles

I am currently programming a diagram editor in `javascript` with `SVG`.

I am stuck with a problem concerning connection between rectangles. I found a lot of resources to draw a connection between circles but nothing about rectangles.

So now what I got is that I can draw a connection line between two rectangles by dragging the line with the mouse but the connection is displayed inside them because i calculate the connection from the middle point of the rectangles.

As You can see in the picture below I made myself some thoughts but i don't get the final step.

I just want to draw the line that is marked red.

[image: Example-picture for my problem: i want to draw the red line]

Later on i want to drag the rectangles and the line should be updated but for now i just need to calculate this line.

Somebody got a good suggestion?

Comment: you've two triangles, a big one with vertices 3,3 8,6 8,3 and a small one 3,3 5,3 5,y given they have the same angles their sides have the same ratios of sizes. From that you can calculate y

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Say you have two rects and you know the center of them (`cx1`, `cy1`) and (`cx2`, `cy2`). You also have the width and height **divided by 2** (i.e. the distance from the center to the sides): (`w1`, `h1`) and (`w2`, `h2`).

The distance between them is:

```
var dx = cx2 - cx1;
var dy = cy2 - cy1;
```

Then you can calculate the intersection point for the two rects with:

```
var p1 = getIntersection(dx, dy, cx1, cy1, w1, h1);
var p2 = getIntersection(-dx, -dy, cx2, cy2, w2, h2);
```

Where `getIntersection` is:

```
function getIntersection(dx, dy, cx, cy, w, h) {
  if (Math.abs(dy / dx) < h / w) {
    // Hit vertical edge of box1
    return [cx + (dx > 0 ? w : -w), cy + dy * w / Math.abs(dx)];
   } else {
    // Hit horizontal edge of box1
    return [cx + dx * h / Math.abs(dy), cy + (dy > 0 ? h : -h)];
    }
};
```

Here's an example:

```js
var rect1 = document.getElementById('rect1');
var rect2 = document.getElementById('rect2');
var cxn = document.getElementById('connection');

updateConnection();

function updateConnection() {
  // Top left coordinates
  var x1 = parseFloat(rect1.getAttributeNS(null, 'x'));
  var y1 = parseFloat(rect1.getAttributeNS(null, 'y'));
  var x2 = parseFloat(rect2.getAttributeNS(null, 'x'));
  var y2 = parseFloat(rect2.getAttributeNS(null, 'y'));

  // Half widths and half heights
  var w1 = parseFloat(rect1.getAttributeNS(null, 'width')) / 2;
  var h1 = parseFloat(rect1.getAttributeNS(null, 'height')) / 2;
  var w2 = parseFloat(rect2.getAttributeNS(null, 'width')) / 2;
  var h2 = parseFloat(rect2.getAttributeNS(null, 'height')) / 2;

  // Center coordinates
  var cx1 = x1 + w1;
  var cy1 = y1 + h1;
  var cx2 = x2 + w2;
  var cy2 = y2 + h2;

  // Distance between centers
  var dx = cx2 - cx1;
  var dy = cy2 - cy1;

  var p1 = getIntersection(dx, dy, cx1, cy1, w1, h1);
  var p2 = getIntersection(-dx, -dy, cx2, cy2, w2, h2);

  cxn.setAttributeNS(null, 'x1', p1[0]);
  cxn.setAttributeNS(null, 'y1', p1[1]);
  cxn.setAttributeNS(null, 'x2', p2[0]);
  cxn.setAttributeNS(null, 'y2', p2[1]);
}

function getIntersection(dx, dy, cx, cy, w, h) {
if (Math.abs(dy / dx) < h / w) {
  // Hit vertical edge of box1
  return [cx + (dx > 0 ? w : -w), cy + dy * w / Math.abs(dx)];
 } else {
  // Hit horizontal edge of box1
  return [cx + dx * h / Math.abs(dy), cy + (dy > 0 ? h : -h)];
  }
};

function makeDraggable(evt) {
  var svg = evt.target;
  svg.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
  svg.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
  svg.addEventListener('mouseup', endDrag);

  function getMousePosition(evt) {
    var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
    return {
      x: (evt.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a,
      y: (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d
    };
  }

  var selectedElement, offset;

  function startDrag(evt) {
    if (evt.target.classList.contains('draggable')) {
      selectedElement = evt.target;
      offset = getMousePosition(evt);
      offset.x -= parseFloat(selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "x"));
      offset.y -= parseFloat(selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "y"));
    }
  }

  function drag(evt) {
    if (selectedElement) {
      var coord = getMousePosition(evt);
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "x", coord.x - offset.x);
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "y", coord.y - offset.y);
      updateConnection();
    }
  }

  function endDrag(evt) {
    selectedElement = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.static {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.draggable {
  cursor: move;
  fill: #007bff;
  fill-opacity: 0.1;
  stroke: #007bff;
  stroke-width: 0.2;
}

#connection {
  stroke-width: 0.1;
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 20" onload="makeDraggable(evt)" width="400" height="200">
    
  <rect id="rect1" class="draggable" x="4" y="5" width="4" height="3"/>
  <rect id="rect2" class="draggable" x="18" y="5" width="3" height="5"/>
  <line id="connection" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you so much works perfect ! and much more thanks for this implementation concerning the draging :)

Comment: @PeterCollingridge can you please explain in more detail what this part in your getIntersection() method `cy + dy * w / Math.abs(dx)` means?