# Line and Rect intersection not calculated properly on one axis

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to achieve a basic d3 network with a connection between two nodes, and I want to have the connection to end at the edge of the destination node (so end-marker is positioned properly) instead of the center of it. I use a `getIntersection()` from [Svg draw connection line between two rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252070/svg-draw-connection-line-between-two-rectangles).

On the Y axis the end point of the link seems to have the right value, but on the X axis an offset appears as I an going further from the origin.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the code that fails:

```js
  graph = {
    "nodes": [{id: 0},{id: 1}],
    "links": [{source: 0,target: 1}]
  }

  const width = 800, height = 600
  const nodeWidth = 80, nodeHeight = 20
  const arrowDepth = 10

  var svg = d3.select("#svg-body").append("svg").attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])

  svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])
    .enter().append("svg:marker")
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", `0 -5 ${arrowDepth} ${arrowDepth}`)
    .attr("refX", 0)
    .attr("refY", -0.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("svg:polyline")
    .attr("points", `0,-5 ${arrowDepth},0 0,5`)
  ;

  let link = svg
    .selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .join("line")
    .classed("link", true)
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")

  const node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .classed("node", true)
    .on("click", click)
    .call(
      d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstart)
      .on("drag", dragged)
    )

  node.append("rect")
    .attr("height", nodeHeight)
    .attr("width", nodeWidth);

  const simulation = d3
    .forceSimulation()
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .force("charge_force",
      d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
    .force("center_force",
      d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force("links",
        d3.forceLink(graph.links)
        .distance(80)
    )
    .on("tick", tick)
    .tick(100)

  function getIntersection(dx, dy, cx, cy, w, h) {
    // Hit vertical edge of box1
    if (Math.abs(dy / dx) < h / w) {
      return [cx + (dx > 0 ? w : -w), cy + dy * w / Math.abs(dx)];
    } else {
      // Hit horizontal edge of box1
      return [cx + dx * h / Math.abs(dy), cy + (dy > 0 ? h : -h)];
    }
  };

  function tick() {

    link
      .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => getIntersection(
        d.source.x-d.target.x,
        d.source.y-d.target.y,
        d.target.x,
        d.target.y,
        nodeWidth,
        nodeHeight
      )[0])
      .attr("y2", d => getIntersection(
        d.source.x-d.target.x,
        d.source.y-d.target.y,
        d.target.x,
        d.target.y,
        nodeWidth,
        nodeHeight
      )[1]);

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return `translate(${d.x - nodeWidth/2}, ${d.y - nodeHeight/2})`; });

  }

  function click(event, d) {
    delete d.fx;
    delete d.fy;
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", false);
    simulation.alpha(1).restart()
  }

  function clamp(x, lo, hi) {
    return x < lo ? lo : x > hi ? hi : x;
  }


  function dragstart() {
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", true);
  }

  function dragged(event, d) {
    d.fx = clamp(event.x, 0, width);
    d.fy = clamp(event.y, 0, height);
    simulation.alpha(1).restart()
  }
```

```css
    .link {
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .node {
        cursor: move;
        fill: #ccc;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .node.fixed {
        fill: #f00;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-body"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the linked example you'll see that the answerer made clear that you have to divide the width and height by 2:

> You also have the width and height **divided by 2**. (their emphasis)

Also, I'm changing `refX` so the arrow head ends exactly at the end of the line.

Here is your code with these changes:

```js
graph = {
  "nodes": [{
    id: 0
  }, {
    id: 1
  }],
  "links": [{
    source: 0,
    target: 1
  }]
}

const width = 800,
  height = 600
const nodeWidth = 80,
  nodeHeight = 20
const arrowDepth = 10

var svg = d3.select("#svg-body").append("svg").attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])

svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
  .data(["end"])
  .enter().append("svg:marker")
  .attr("id", String)
  .attr("viewBox", `0 -5 ${arrowDepth} ${arrowDepth}`)
  .attr("refX", 10)
  .attr("refY", 0)
  .attr("markerWidth", 6)
  .attr("markerHeight", 6)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:polyline")
  .attr("points", `0,-5 ${arrowDepth},0 0,5`);

let link = svg
  .selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .join("line")
  .classed("link", true)
  .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")

const node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .classed("node", true)
  .on("click", click)
  .call(
    d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstart)
    .on("drag", dragged)
  )

node.append("rect")
  .attr("height", nodeHeight)
  .attr("width", nodeWidth);

const simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation()
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .force("charge_force",
    d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
  .force("center_force",
    d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("links",
    d3.forceLink(graph.links)
    .distance(80)
  )
  .on("tick", tick)
  .tick(100)

function getIntersection(dx, dy, cx, cy, w, h) {
  // Hit vertical edge of box1
  if (Math.abs(dy / dx) < h / w) {
    return [cx + (dx > 0 ? w : -w), cy + dy * w / Math.abs(dx)];
  } else {
    // Hit horizontal edge of box1
    return [cx + dx * h / Math.abs(dy), cy + (dy > 0 ? h : -h)];
  }
};

function tick() {

  link
    .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
    .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
    .attr("x2", d => getIntersection(
      d.source.x - d.target.x,
      d.source.y - d.target.y,
      d.target.x,
      d.target.y,
      nodeWidth / 2,
      nodeHeight / 2
    )[0])
    .attr("y2", d => getIntersection(
      d.source.x - d.target.x,
      d.source.y - d.target.y,
      d.target.x,
      d.target.y,
      nodeWidth / 2,
      nodeHeight / 2
    )[1]);

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return `translate(${d.x - nodeWidth/2}, ${d.y - nodeHeight/2})`;
  });

}

function click(event, d) {
  delete d.fx;
  delete d.fy;
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", false);
  simulation.alpha(1).restart()
}

function clamp(x, lo, hi) {
  return x < lo ? lo : x > hi ? hi : x;
}


function dragstart() {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", true);
}

function dragged(event, d) {
  d.fx = clamp(event.x, 0, width);
  d.fy = clamp(event.y, 0, height);
  simulation.alpha(1).restart()
}
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  cursor: move;
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.fixed {
  fill: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-body"></div>
```